# SKAction repeated forever

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I limit the number of time that my SkAction is running?

```
if pointsLabel.number > highscoreLabel.number{
            runAction(bestScore)

        highscoreLabel.setTo(pointsLabel.number)

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(highscoreLabel.number, forKey: "highscore")

        }
```

and

```
var bestScore = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("1up", waitForCompletion: false)
```

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

To repeat an action certain number of times, rather than repeating it forever, you can use [+ repeatAction:count:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/repeatAction:count:) method. From the docs:

> Creates an action that repeats another action a specified number of
>   times. When the action executes, the associated action runs to
>   completion and then repeats, until the count is reached.This action is
>   reversible; it creates a new action that is the reverse of the
>   specified action and then repeats it the same number of times.

Important thing to keep in mind is that an action to be repeated must have a non-instantaneous duration.

Comment: I can't declare my function in the specific place I want it to run!